# Python Selenium PhantomJS - Extract download link of file that is being downloaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

So as the title suggests, I am trying to get the direct link of a downloading file using PhantomJS through selenium in Python 3.7

The site I am working on is emuparadise.me, I am downloading a rom file with a request to this [link](https://www.emuparadise.me/roms/get-download.php?gid=154652&test=true) after adding a cookie to avoid getting "Invalid Referer" error. When the request is made `browser.current_url` shows `about:blank` and I know that the file has started downloading by checking network usage for PhantomJS. Having been browsing the internet for over 3 hours now, I haven't found any way of retrieving the url of the downloading file.

One of my thoughts for a solution was creating a thread for tracking changes to `browser.current_url` but it seems like `browser` locks up when making the request

Here is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.add_cookie({'name': 'refexception', 'value': 1, 'domain': '.emuparadise.me', 'path': '/'})
browser.get("https://www.emuparadise.me/roms/get-download.php?gid=154652&test=true")
```

Note that I don't care at all about downloading the file, neither do I know or need to know where it's being downloaded. I've discovered the actual [link](http://50.7.189.186/happyxhJ1ACmlTrxJQpol71nBc/Playstation2Europe/isos/Test%20Drive%20Unlimited%20(Europe)%20(En,Fr,De,Es).7z) for that specific example file from firefox in case you need it for testing. I also really prefer using PhantomJS over Firefox or Chrome web drivers for such a simple looking task. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: PhantomJS is deprecated

Comment: So? I explained why I am using it..

Comment: It was a comment for future readers who are wondering why your code doesn't work anymore.  It's nice to know when you are using deprecated code so you can be aware of it's pending removal.

Comment: Oh, alright then, I'll keep it in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally came up to the solution. Since I know that the download url must be somewhere in the headers of my request, I searched for a way to view them for PhantomJS. It was pretty easy, indeed. All I did was change the log level from `INFO`(default) to `DEBUG` and the headers appeared in the log file under the events `page.onResourceRequested` and `page.onResourceReceived`. After making the request, I am just parsing the log file looking for the latter event and scraping out the url. Here's the complete code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from json import loads


def get_direct_url_for_game(url):
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=["--webdriver-loglevel=DEBUG"])
    browser.add_cookie({'name': 'refexception', 'value': 1, 'domain': '.emuparadise.me', 'path': '/'})
    browser.get(download_url)

    direct_download_url = None
    with open('ghostdriver.log') as logs:
        for line in logs:
            _, _, event, event_data = line.split(" - ")
            if event == "page.onResourceReceived":
                event_data = loads(event_data)
                if event_data['contentType'] == "application/octet-stream":
                    direct_download_url = event_data['url']
                    browser.quit()
    return direct_download_url


print(get_url_for_game("https://www.emuparadise.me/roms/get-download.php?gid=154652&test=true"))
```

---

**EDIT:**

I actually found out a much simpler way of achieving the exact same thing much easier and more elegantly using `requests`' `head` function. This is making a request for the HTTP Headers of the url, hence the name, and we will still pass in the same cookie. We will allow redirects since that's what we want and the url will be under the variable `url` of the request.

Here's a look at it:

```
from requests import head


def get_direct_url_for_game(url):
    request = head(game_url, allow_redirects=True, cookies={'refexception': '1'})
    return request.url


print(get_direct_url_for_game("https://www.emuparadise.me/roms/get-download.php?gid=154652&test=true"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The php page is serving the file.  You can't get the path or real filename on client side.  (Added: now that I re-read your question I guess you did get the link client side!... you learn something new everyday!  But, Selenium does not have acccess beyond the DOM.)

Comment: the only way would be to sort of hack it... try to get an error to appear with path or filename and deduce the rest.  This would not be a very nice thing to do and could be considered malicious.  There's probably a reason they are serving the file in this way.  (They don't want you to direct link to it...)

Comment: now that I see Firefox had the path, you could do this with some sort of Firefox plug-in which writes the path into the page.  You could then extract it from the DOM using Selenium.